# 'jQuery' type function for manipulating clojure maps

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, noir

Is there a jQuery type function to solve the problem of walking through nested maps?

for example, if i have a configuration that looks like this:

```
  (def fig
    {:config
      {:example
        {:a "a"
         :b "b"
         :c "c"}
       :more
        {:a "a"
         :b "b"
         :c "c"}}})
```

I still haven't figured out a great way to manipulate nested persistent data structures with assoc and dissoc. However, if there was a `jquery` style way to manipulate maps, then I can write code like this:

```
  (->  fig
    ($ [:config :example :a] #(str % "a"))
    ($ [:config :b] #(str % "b")))

  Giving this output:

  {:config
    {:example
      {:a "aa"
       :b "bb"
       :c "c"}
     :more
      {:a "a"
       :b "bb"
       :c "c"}}}
```

And something like this for selectors:

```
($ fig [:config :example :a])
  ;=> "a"

($ fig [:config :b])
  ;=> {[:config :example :b] "b", 
  ;    [:config :more :b] "b"}
```

So in essence, I'm looking for an implementation of `jayq` for manipulation of clojure objects instead of html doms.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should check out Enlive.

Otherwise: if you want to do what jQuery does (of course very simplified) - as opposed to just calling update-in:

**Select:**

```
(defn clj-query-select [obj path]
  (if (empty? path)
    (list obj)
    (when (map? obj)
      (apply concat
        (remove nil? 
          (for [[key value] obj]
            (clj-query-select
              value 
              (if (= key (first path)) (rest path) path))))))))
```

For call:

```
(clj-query-select {:a {:b 1} :b 2} [:b])
```

it should yield:

```
(1 2)
```

**Update/replace:**

```
(defn clj-query-update [obj path fn]
  (if (empty? path)
    (fn obj)
    (if (map? obj)
      (into obj
        (remove nil?
          (for [[key value] obj]
            (let [res (clj-query-update 
                        value 
                        (if (= key (first path)) (rest path) path)
                        fn)]
          (when (not= res value) [key res])))))
      obj)))
```

For call:

```
(clj-query-update {:c {:a {:b 1} :b 2}} [:c :b] #(* % 2))
```

it should yield:

```
{:c {:a {:b 2} :b 4}}
```

*I didn't test it thoroughly though.*

Comment: Thanks! that'll give me a nice template to play around with!

Comment: The problem I have with this code is that it is creating a new structure each time it is called. I don't think update-in does that, but instead returns a modified version of the original

Comment: In general Clojure functions do not modify passed objects. It is implemented in such a way that making a clone of a clojure data structure is very fast.
Unless you mean the (into {} ... part?

Comment: yeah... the `into {}` part is what I was refering to

Comment: It should now only replace the changed submaps.

Comment: oh fantastic! the `into` function is great.

Answer (score 6):

`update-in` is a great function for updating nested maps.

```
user> (def data {:config
{:example  {:a "a" :b "b" :c "c"}}
 :more {:a "a" :b "b" :c "c"}})

user> (pprint (update-in data [:config :example] assoc :d 4))

{:config {:example {:a "a", :c "c", :b "b", :d 4}},
 :more {:a "a", :c "c", :b "b"}}
```

`assoc-in` may be a little closer to what you want

```
user> (pprint (assoc-in data [:config :example :d] 4))
{:config {:example {:a "a", :c "c", :b "b", :d 4}},
 :more {:a "a", :c "c", :b "b"}}
```

for reading values without changing them you can use the fact that keywords look themselves up in maps to write an even more compact form than the jquery form

```
user> (-> data :config :example :a)
"a"
```

Comment: +1 Is there a way to change update-in to make it more jquery like? (The reason is that I'm trying to manipulate hiccup structures)

Comment: For completeness sake: there is also `get-in`.